# Devise integration with Facebook AppCenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I have an application which integrates with facebook via oauth2 devise/warden/omniauth. Everything works find and I am happy with it.

Now I'm trying to integrate the app with the new facebook appcenter, which basically seems to resolve into getting the user *pre* authenticated before he gest to my site.

Basically, the user ends on a url like

```
/?fb_appcenter=1&code=xxxxxx
```

but devise' omniauthcontroller is waiting on a different url, namely

```
/users/auth/facebook/callback
```

I tried to perform a simple redirect carrying over the code query parameter to the callback url, but I get an "invalid credentials" error.

I believe the issue may be that the redirect_uri used in the call to get an access_token within the oauth2 facebook strategy does not correspond to the one used by facebook itself to generate the initial code, but I have no idea on how I am supposed to change that.

Anyone has suggestions or has solved this in the past?

For what is worth, I'm using an old version of devise (1.4) and omniauth (0.3) but a hint of what the general direction should be, even if with newer versions, would be good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it turns out this is impossible with old versions of omniauth, since `redirect_uri` is hardcoded, but a reasonable trick is to just redirect the user to the standard auth callback (e.g. `/auth/facebook/callback`).

This will authenticate the user again, but since he already gave you credentials it will just get through.

The alternative, and what I endd up doing, is to just get the code from OA's facebook strategy and reimplement a bit of the OAuth2 functionality, basically exchanging the code with an access token, in the landing page you are using.

Answer (score 0):

When exchanging the code for a token, where the code was created in an authenticated referral, the `redirect_uri` value needs to be the same URL the user was brought to.
There's a note to this effect on the [App Center documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/#authorization):

**A special consideration when using the Query String setting:**

If you would like to use the server-side authentication flow with App Center it is important to make sure you are passing the redirect_uri parameter correctly when exchanging your code for an access token. You should set your redirect_uri parameter to the click-through URL to your site. In most cases the URL will look something like:

`http://www.example.com/?fb_appcenter=1&fb_source=search&code=CODE_HERE`
thus you should set your redirect_uri to the same value. Please make sure that this logic is dynamic as the query parameters appended to your click-through URL may be subject to change.

Comment: yes, but how can I convince omniauth/devise to use a different redirect_uri than the one it uses by default (which I think is '', the empty string)